# One to one join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, one-to-one

I need to join two table on one common column, but I want to maintain a one-to-one relation on other two column. For example:

table_1

```
ID_C   ID_ROW_C   OPT
C      1          10   
C      2          10
```

table_2

```
ID_F   ID_ROW_F   OPT
F      3          10   
F      4          10
```

My query:

```
select *  
from table_1, table_2  
where table_1.OPT=table_2.OPT
```

result

```
ID_C   ID_ROW_C   OPT   ID_F   ID_ROW_F  
C      1          10    F      3  
C      1          10    F      4  
C      2          10    F      3  
C      2          10    F      4
```

desired result:

```
ID_C   ID_ROW_C   OPT   ID_F   ID_ROW_F
C      1          10    F      4  
C      2          10    F      3
```

or

```
ID_C   ID_ROW_C   OPT   ID_F   ID_ROW_F
C      1          10    F      3  
C      2          10    F      4
```

How can I do?

Comment: Besides the `OPT` field, how do you relate the columns from each table with the other? You're getting what's expected (if you only join the `OPT` column, you'll get all combinations with the matching rows)... you need to define some criteria to relate the other rows.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use `JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
ON table_1.OPT = table_2.OPT
```

More info from the MySQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

And a relevant Stack Overflow discussion on the different types of `JOIN`s: [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: This is not what I have to do. I want to get only 2 rows from this query, not 4.

Comment: Looks like @barranka's answer should get you closer, but I'd have a look at your table design if this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing any rule to relate the columns, you're getting *exactly* what you're supposed to get: All the rows of both tables that fulfill the relation.

However, you can create an "artificial" condition to get what you want... it's not pretty, but it will work:

```
select t1.id_c, t1.id_row_c
     , t1.opt
     , t2.id_f, t2.id_row_f
from
    (
        select @r_id_1 := (case 
                   when @prev_opt_1 = table_1.opt then @r_id_1 + 1 
                   else 1
               end) as r_id
             , table_1.*
             , @prev_opt_1 := table_1.opt as new_opt_1
        from (select @r_id_1 := 0, @prev_opt_1 := 0) as init_1
           , table_1
        order by table_1.opt, table_1.id_row_c
    ) as t1
    inner join (
        select @r_id_2 := (case
                   when @prev_opt_2 = table_2.opt then @r_id_2 + 1 
                   else 1
               end) as r_id
             , table_2.*
             , @prev_opt_2 := table_2.opt as new_opt_2
        from (select @r_id_2 := 0, @prev_opt_2 := 0) as init_2, table_2
        order by table_2.opt, table_2.id_row_f
    ) as t2 on t1.opt = t2.opt and t1.r_id = t2.r_id
```

See the result at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27e82/4).

**The explanation**

Let's take the first subquery:

```
select @r_id_1 := (case 
           when @prev_opt_1 = table_1.opt then @r_id_1 + 1 
           else 1
       end) as r_id
     , table_1.*
     , @prev_opt_1 := table_1.opt as new_opt_1
from (select @r_id_1 := 0, @prev_opt_1 := 0) as init_1
   , table_1
order by table_1.opt, table_1.id_row_c
```

In the `from` clause for this query, I'm declaring two user variables and initializing them to zero. The `@r_id_1` variable will increase by one if the previous value of `@prev_opt_1` is equal to the current value of `opt`, or reset to 1 if the value is different. The variable `@prev_opt_1` will take the value of the `opt` column *after* the `@r_id_1` variable is set. This means that, for each `opt` value, the `@r_id_1` variable will have an increasing value.

The second subquery does exactly the same for the other table.

Finally, the outer-most query will join both subqueries using `opt` *and* the increasing Id.

Take the time to understand what's going on behind scenes (execute each subquery separatedly and see what happens).

---

As I said, this solution is "artificial"... it's a way to get what you need, but to avoid this  <strike>dirty and quite complex</strike>  hard solutions, you need to rethink your tables, and make them more easy to relate with each other.

Hope this helps